# Does the allocate_output function set values to be zeros in default in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

In tensorflow, we should use this code to allocate output tensor:

```
    Tensor* output_tensor = NULL;
    OP_REQUIRES_OK(context, context->allocate_output(0, TensorShape({depth, height, width, num_classes}), 
                                                     &output_tensor));
```

My question is, will this allocation set the values in this output tensor to be zeros? Or do we need to manually to fill the tensor to be zeros?

Comment: my guess is "no" because automatic initialization would be wasteful -- typically ops produce tensors other than "all zeros", so you would be initializing this memory twice

Comment: Hi, @YaroslavBulatov, thanks for comment. It seems the default values are zeros after this function. So we don't need to fill them manually. But I'm not sure if this is compiler-related.

Comment: the semantics are described in `framework/op_kernel.h`. I see at least one allocation path going through malloc [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2d8da1d9bd4aaf159b65d5b3d567e79fd41ace23/tensorflow/core/platform/posix/port.cc#L98) which doesn't clear memory in all cases

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov, thanks for your kind extensive explanation. I run my code without manually allocating zeros to the memory, but the result output tensor have all zeros filled. Thus I think this would be compiler-done work. I remember (but not sure) that the modern C++ compiler could do this thing automatically.

Comment: I've noticed this too, but I think you can't rely on it. When kernel was run on the CPU, it did not seem to be initialized to zero, while my GPU kernel tended to be zero.